# How to find java packages to import with Sublime Text 3?

Tags: java, sublime-text-3, ide, sublime-text

In Java IDE's there is usually a feature that suggests/auto-completes imports, however with sublime text, I end up searching for packages to import

I'm wondering whether there is an internal feature that enables this, or a lightweight/non-intrusive plugin that searches packages to import based on the name/thing-to-import

Edit: My solution in a gist, as requested: https://gist.github.com/kaansoral/aed8c5d56f262ed1d63a

Comment: should be on stackoverflow there is a similar one where a developer says he hasn't done support for import http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9369617/is-there-a-way-add-auto-completion-support-for-java-to-sublime-text-2    Just ask a qusetion specifying imports

Comment: does https://github.com/quarnster/sublimejava  do it?

Comment: After more research, JavaImports plugin does what I need, it's pretty lightweight too, but not compatible with ST3 (at least not explicity) - I'm probably going to adjust the logic and adapt it to become a command line script: https://github.com/MDeiml/SublimeJavaImports/blob/master/JavaAddImport.py

Comment: if you do make that adaption, it'd be great if you make it public and provide a link to it

Comment: done, updated the answer, thanks for your interest